# Comparison of two methods used to calculate capacitance

Tags: capacitor, measurement

I need to compare two potential methods used to calculate capacitance, but I can't find the names for them to do some research.

The first method: Placing a capacitor in a circuit with an 800 Hz alternating current and a multimeter, and calculate the capacitance with the following formula :

$$ C = \frac{I}{\omega V}$$

From what I gather, this method is called impedance spectroscopy, but I'm really not sure.

The second method: Placing a capacitor in series with a resistor, still with a circuit frequency of 800 Hz. Short-circuiting the capacitor, with alternating current, to find \$I_0\$ and then finding \$I\$ when the current passes through it, then finding the capacitance with :

$$ C = \frac{1}{R \omega \sqrt{((\frac{I_0}{I})^2}-1)} $$

I *think* this may be the charge-discharge method.
I'm really not sure, from what I've read neither of these are right.